# PHP json_encode() returns nothing

Tags: java, php, android, json

OK, few days ago I wrote a block of code in Java that sends post requests to a PHP file in order to store some data in a MySQL database and receive back simple json_encode() strings such as "error_101" responses from PHP and it worked just fine. Yesterday I reinstalled my XAMPP because I've had some problems with openssl PHP extention and now none of my json_encode() reponses return a value. I've checked the phpinfo() and it says that json support is enabled. To mention that values sent to PHP from JAVA are JSON objects as well and the json_decode() works just fine!

Here's my code to send responses from PHP to JAVA:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode("error_101");
?>
```

Here's the code to get the response in JAVA

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

String url = "http://192.168.254.19/android/register.php";

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
request.setHeader("json", json.toString());

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String result = null;
if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

    InputStreamReader is_reader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is_reader);
    result = br.readLine();
    Log.i("Read from server", result);
    Toast.makeText(this,  result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The response I'm getting is "`<br />`"

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting? That <br> looks like a silenced error to me.

Comment: You say, "Yesterday I reinstalled my XAMPP ..."  That may well mean that some settings got changed back to their default.  Might be useful to check them all.

Answer (score 1):

You sure you don't have some debug code somewhere up the chain that reads

```
echo $TesttVar1 . '<br />';
```

That would also stop the "header()" from working. Turn on ALL errors (error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');  ) and that will show you the line the 
 is output, if that's the case.

But to help weed it out if it is json_encode, just return "Error_101" without the function to test. But I don't think you're getting that far down the program.

Comment: I've checked the code and I don't have any 'echo' statements at all except three echo json_encode(value) statements inside different if else statement blocks.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode needs an array. like

```
json_encode(array('status'=>'error_101'));
```

Comment: You should be able to json_encode a string - you'd get {"Error_101"}. It's just most commonly used with arrays.  (Correction - as pointed below, it would return "Error_101" - thanks prehfeldt)

Comment: @Robbie: that's not true either! If you encode a string to json you get "error_101" for example. See the third diagram on this page: http://www.json.org/

Comment: Yep - sorry. Rushed typing. But the point it you can json_encode almost anything.

Comment: It should work with simple strings as well with int values. I've used responses like json_encode(101) and it worked.

Comment: @prehfeldt yes it is the case with using a simple string it just prints the string only. using array('str') returns it as ['str']

Answer (score 0):

in this case:

```
header("Content-type: text/html");
echo json_encode("error_101");
```

it works.

in this other case:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode("error_101");
```

it doesn't work.

It seems a bug!